# Create a new user with an underscore in the name

Tags: xml, wix, windows-installer

I am trying to create a user in WiX, using the following XML:

```
  <Component Id="cmp_MyNewFolder" Guid="*">
    <util:User Id="MyNewUser"
      CreateUser="yes"
      Name="DUMMY&#95;USER"
      Domain="[ComputerName]"
      Password=""
      PasswordNeverExpires="yes"
      RemoveOnUninstall="yes"
      UpdateIfExists="yes" />
    <CreateFolder>
      <util:PermissionEx GenericAll="yes" User="DUMMY&#95;USER"/>
    </CreateFolder>
  </Component>
```

I've removed the GUID and password for this post, so the issue isn't with those. The problem is that whenever I run the .MSI, I get a generic error (Failed to create user) and the installation fails. After playing around with the XML a bit, I found out that giving the user a name that contains an underscore was causing the error. I have tried using the character literal and the XML entity for an underscore, but it is the same result either way.

What confuses me is that (based on what I've read) an underscore isn't considered to be a special character, and I have been able to create this user manually (with the underscore) without any problems. Is it possible to create a user with an underscore in the name, using WiX? Or will I have to settle for a different character?

Comment: Which version of WIX are you using?  Could you post the portion of the install log that relates to the "Failed to create user" error?

Comment: The error in the install log seems to contain a number of different error codes:

CreateUser:  Error 0x80070563: failed to create user: DUMMY_USER
Error 26401. Failed to create user.  (-2147023517   DUMMY_USER      )
MSI (s) (D0!DC) [14:38:14:158]: Product: wix_test -- Error 26401. Failed to create user.  (-2147023517   DUMMY_USER      )

CustomAction CreateUser returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 14:38:14: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.

I've looked them up, but they don't seem to pertain to a common issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is allowed to use an underscore in the user's name. This code works and the installation package correctly creates the user.

```
<Component Id="Component_User" Guid="{1B55F3FB-6B0F-4EF9-89ED-DB3ECA9106A4}">
    <util:User Id="MyNewUser"
               CreateUser="yes"
               Name="test_user"
               Password="test"
               PasswordNeverExpires="yes"
               RemoveOnUninstall="yes"
               UpdateIfExists="yes" />
    <CreateFolder>
        <util:PermissionEx GenericAll="yes" User="test_user"/>
    </CreateFolder>
</Component>
```

The verbose log might have more information about the error.

Comment: The verbose log around the error looks like this:


`CreateUser:  Error 0x80070563: failed to create user: IIS_IUSRS
Error 26401. Failed to create user.  (-2147023517   IIS_IUSRS      )
MSI (s) (D0!DC) [14:38:14:158]: Product: wix_test -- Error 26401. Failed to create user.  (-2147023517   IIS_IUSRS      )

CustomAction CreateUser returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 14:38:14: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.`


I've looked at the error codes, but I don't see how they're related to what I'm doing.

Comment: In WinError.h, this error 0x80070563 is described as ERROR_ALIAS_EXISTS (The specified local group already exists.). It occurs because an user with the same name already exists (would it be possible to be only deactivated?).

Comment: I've replaced the username with something I hadn't previously used and the installer worked. I can only assume that I ran the installer at one point without using the "RemoveOnUninstall" attribute, and the user is still hanging around somewhere. I'd like to fully remove them from the system, but I can't find them anywhere. This is another issue though. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Error 0x80070563 (-2147023517) is `ERROR_ALIAS_EXISTS` (The specified local group already exists.)  It occurs when you attempt to create a user, but a user group (or other AD object?) already exists with the same name.

I don't think there is anything wrong with your installer.  Underscores in names aren't anything special.  The problem appears to be a user group (or other AD object) that already exists on the computer where you are running the installer.  The installer is attempting to create the user but can't because of the clash.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error with WiX Toolset v3. I had punctuation marks in the password field, and even though they are valid, it caused the installation to fail. Possible bug.